# Minimal, single file, 5 star rating system for PHP to inject into HTML

Tags: php, rating

I am looking for a simple 5-star rating system which my PHP can inject into its HTML.

Any CSS and JS should be inline, not requiring separate files, and when the user clicks a star, I want to add code to take an action (inform my server of the rating by HTTP AJAX)